# Swift: Unable to communicate data between view controllers when using present

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, tvos

I have implemented these **programmatically**.

**TableViewCell:**

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

    var moviesItems: [Document] = []

    @objc func didPressVoirToutButton() {
        print("Voir tout button was pressed.")
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
           let vc: VoirToutViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VoirToutViewController") as! VoirToutViewController
           self.viewController?.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
           print("moviesItemsArray being communicated to moviesItems",moviesItems) 
           // moviesItems is not empty
            vc.voirToutMoviesItemsArray=self.moviesItems
    }
}
```

**VoirToutViewController:**

```
class VoirToutViewController: UIViewController {
    var voirToutMoviesItemsArray : [Document]?
}
```

I am trying to communicate `moviesItems` from `TableViewController` to `VoirToutViewController` by setting it to `voirToutMoviesItemsArray`.

The **problem** is  `VoirToutViewController.voirToutMoviesItemsArray` always remains empty.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `moviesItems` itself is non-empty? What is `self.viewController`? Why don't you just do `self.present(...)`?

Comment: You are not showing all relevant lines of code.  How could we tell that VoirToutViewController is not receiving voirToutMoviesItemsArray?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, moviesItems is not empty as it gets logged correctly. The TableViewController is actually tableViewCell in my code that's why I use self.vieewController? . I'll fix it

Comment: @ElTomato because I log it in ViewDidLoad and it's empty

Comment: No view controller will receive a variable from another at `ViewDidLoad`.

Comment: @ElTomato I didn't get that

Comment: Perform this `vc.voirToutMoviesItemsArray=self.moviesItems` before you perform `self.viewController?.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nil because you are presenting the vc before you initialize its value. To fix:

Place this line

`vc.voirToutMoviesItemsArray=self.moviesItems`

before this one

`self.viewController?.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)`

Comment: Thank you that fixed my problem.